# can anyone explain what this is 802.3 over multimode?

Tags: networking

is some sort of lan communication technology anyone know some insite to this subject and point me to the right direction thanks

Comment: Please do not migrate to SF, was cross posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is a a LAN communication technology.  Specifically, it is [Gigabit Ethernet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabit_Ethernet) over [Multi-mode fiber](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-mode_fiber).

To simplify it further, it is a high-speed local network using optical fiber connections.

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.3) has an explanation, but it's quite long. [802.3aq](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/802.3aq) is called "10GBASE-LRM 10 Gbit/s (1,250 MB/s) Ethernet over multimode fiber", perhaps that is what you're after.